# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2)

Tags: flutter

I want to showing data from this pages
[image]

But when I click Loan Simulation button, It showing this error

```
    E/flutter ( 4439): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2)
    E/flutter ( 4439): [
E/flutter ( 4439): #6      LoanModel.simulators (package:fluttermysql/LoanModel.dart:51:34)
E/flutter ( 4439): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4439): #7      _LoanSimulationState.result (package:fluttermysql/view/LoanSimulation.dart:30:5)
E/flutter ( 4439): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is my LoanModel.Simulators

```
  static Future<LoanModel> simulators({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest, String idUser, String url}) async  {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;
    final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type":
    "application/json"});
    var res = LoanModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body[0])); //without [0] it showing error Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
    print(response.body);
    return res;
  }
```

Here is process of loansimulation

```
void result() async {
    LoanModel loanModel;
    await LoanModel.simulators(
        periodtime: periodtime,
        interestpermonth: interestpermonth,
        loanamountrequest: loanamountrequest,
        url: BaseURL.kLoanSimulationUrl2)
        .then((value) => loanModel = value as LoanModel);
    print(loanModel.status);
    if (loanModel.status == true) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Simulator.id);
    } else {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(loanModel.message),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      ));
    }
  }
```

the link of BaseURL is http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php (without parameter)
I want to showing to listview based on [Flutter Https Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569390/flutter-https-unhandled-exception-invalid-arguments)

the response.body with [0] I got is

```
[{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"10,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"100,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"10,000,000.00","Installment":"10,100,000.00","Status":true}]
```

Here is my Loan Model

```
class LoanModel {
  int no;
  String interest;
  String balance;
  String principal;
  String installment;
  bool status;
  String message;

  LoanModel(
      {this.no,
        this.interest,
        this.balance,
        this.principal,
        this.installment,
        this.status,
      this.message});

  LoanModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    no = json['No'];
    interest = json['interest'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    principal = json['principal'];
    installment = json['Installment'];
    status = json['Status'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['No'] = this.no;
    data['interest'] = this.interest;
    data['balance'] = this.balance;
    data['principal'] = this.principal;
    data['Installment'] = this.installment;
    data['Status'] = this.status;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    return data;
  }
}
```

How to fix that error? there's no solution about it.

Comment: Hi There. Update your question with the output you are receiving from `response.body`. Put a `print` and paste it here.

Comment: [{"No":0,"interest":"0.00","balance":"11,000,000,000.00","principal":"0.00","Installment":"0.00","Status":true},{"No":1,"interest":"110,000,000.00","balance":"0.00","principal":"11,000,000,000.00","Installment":"11,110,000,000.00","Status":true}]

Comment: Post you `LoanModel` class as well.

Comment: i already update my question with model.

Comment: I added an answer. check if it works for you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be few mistakes in the code, which I will point out,

```
static Future<LoanModel> simulators({String periodtime, String interestpermonth, String loanamountrequest, String idUser, String url}) async  {
  // This var url is a String
  var url = "http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=" + periodtime + "&interestpermonth=" + interestpermonth + "&loanamountrequest=" +loanamountrequest;

  // Here you are using url directly, but http.get requires a Uri object
  // You have already specified the content-type here. so your response will be a jsonObject itself.
  final response = await http.get(url,headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"});

  // Since your response is already a jsonObject, you don't need jsonDecode here, just use LoanModel.fromJson(response.body[0]);
  var res = LoanModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body[0])); //without [0] it showing error Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
  print(response.body);
  return res;
}
```

So, the main issue should be this line,

```
var res = LoanModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body[0]));
```

Change it to

```
var res = LoanModel.fromJson(response.body[0]);
```

since your `response.body` is already a `json object`, that's why you are able to access `response.body[0]`.

Also, you said `without [0] it showing error`. This is because your `response.body` is a `List` of `json object` i.e., `List<Map<String, dynamic>`. But your `LoadModel.fromJson` takes only a `Map<String,dynamic>` not a `List`.
That is why you have to take one element with `[0]` and pass it to `fromJson`.

Comment: it make this error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: If that error comes up, then your `response.body[0]` is not what you posted in your question. Can you give your url you using to fetch your data ?

Comment: Is your api public ? since I am not able to access it with the url you have provided.

Comment: with this fine http://192.168.0.23/edufund-api/Api/loansimulation.php?periodtime=48&interestpermonth=1&loanamountrequest=11000000. But thats not correct because it should be input value first the showing as list in other pages

Comment: no. My API is private in local host server

Comment: ok go to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67569390/flutter-https-unhandled-exception-invalid-arguments